# How do I make my Perl scripts act like normal programs on Linux

Tags: linux, perl, icons

Perl programs I've written earlier were simple text processing scripts, for executing them I use to use terminal. Now I am learning GUI programming(I want to make some games as a hobby), using Tcl/TK library for Perl.

I've used a sample Hello, World! dialog program provided in the   tutorial. When I execute it using terminal it was working properly, but when I try to execute by clicking the file icon, its giving me some options, like

run in terminal, Display, Cancel, Run

None of them are producing any dialog-box, previously it produced when executed using terminal.

I've searched Google for any suggestions, but I found none. Many of them are facing the same issue(from un-answered questions in various forums).

1. When I double-click on `hello-world_tcl.pl` I want it to execute it.
2. Can I change the icon of the executable script ?

Answer (score 0):

It should run properly when you choose "Run", if it doesn't, you have another problem as well.

To run your script without having that dialog appear and to change its icon, you will need to create a `.desktop` file for it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My script
Comment=Test hellow world script
Exec=/home/user/myscript.pl
Icon=/home/user/myicon.gif
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Save the file on your `Desktop` folder as `myscript.desktop`, it should now appear using the icon `/home/user/myicon.gif` and you can run it by double clicking.